# how to find the latest inserted data from two table using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table name 
tbl_audio and tbl_video.
both tables have the same things. id,name,date, u_id.

Here u_id is a foreign key.
Now I want to show the last uploaded file from two table.
Suppose

[this is tbl_audio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PKTe.jpg)

[this is tbl_video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DavWx.jpg)

Here video3 is the last uploaded file according to date from two tables. I want to find this name(video3) by joining both tables.
thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: You'll get better response if you type it in instead of images, sample data, sample data genaretion, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should union both tables and find the top 1 of they by date:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
 SELECT id, name, date, u_id FROM tbl_audio
  UNION ALL
 SELECT id, name, date, u_id FROM tbl_video
) as T
ORDER BY Date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Also consider to use the one table to store all data say `tbl_media` with additional field `media_type` (audio or video).

Comment: wow. thanksss its work now. Many many thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try use trigger. You can create log table to save last insert. Trigger **AFTER INSERT** will always update log table.

About create trigger you can read in [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: thakns for your respone. got my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MAX()` function and get the latest entry in the table like

```
select max(name) as latest_video
from tbl_video;
```

If you want data from both table on the matched `u_id` then perform a `JOIN` between them and use the `max()` function to get the latest audio/video file name.

Comment: On what columns would you join? I do not see any meaningful join here.

Comment: @Seb, I see both table has `u_id` column. Not sure but OP has to confirm

Comment: thakns for your respone. got my answer.